# Prevent a user from sharing a page multiple times on facebook

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I have put a share button on a php page and the share button is functioning well. If someone shares that page the story is published to the timeline. Now I want every user to be able to share only once. In other words a user should not be able to share the page multiple times. How can we prevent users from sharing a page multiple times?

The url of the page being shared:
http://www.shantacreations.com/facebook_share_old/example_1/share.php/

Answer (score 0):

> How can we prevent users from sharing a page multiple times?

You can’t – not really.

You *could* have users connect to your app first, and do the “sharing” via the API – and safe the fact that they shared the page together with their user id to your database, and deny sharing the next time they try it inside of your app.

But that will not prevent them from sharing it again themselves over the facebook.com website.

Comment: how to i get user id in my database,i have to use any database for this on my server ?,my code is as below.

Comment: $title=urlencode("How to Create a Custom Facebook Share Button with a Custom Counter");
$url=urlencode("http://shantacreations.com/facebook_share_old/example_1/share.php/");
$summary=urlencode("Learn how to create a custom Facebook 'Share' button, complete with a custom counter, for your website!");
$image=urlencode("http://shantacreations.com/facebook_share_old/example_1/images/subhash_pics.jpg");
$redirect_uri=urlencode("http://shantacreations.com/facebook_share_old/example_1/subhash.php");

Comment: <a id="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=550,height=400');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)">Click to Share</a>

Comment: cbroe i want to know from you,how to get the user id from that page,and when i have to check that the user is whether in my database or not,so will you please tell me all this steps in details,thanks to help me,and now i am waiting for your reply.